# What is the output of this program, and why?

Tags: c

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <unistd.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <string.h>
>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[])
> {
>     int num;
>     int num_set = 0;
>     int len;
>     int opt;
>
>     while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "vn:o:")) >= 0) {
>       switch (opt) {
>         case 'v': printf("802"); break;
>         case 'n': num_set = 1; num = atoi(optarg); printf("%i", num); break;
>         case 'o': len = strlen(optarg); printf("%i", len); break;
>       }
>     }
>
>     if (!num_set) { printf("0"); exit(1); }
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Given the code above, what's the output if we run the program with the command `./prog -vn 5 -o 4026`?

I have been trying to solve this problem, and keep getting the output `80254026`. This, however, is not correct. Here's a breakdown of my thinking process:

1. The program uses the getopt function to parse the command-line arguments.
2. The switch statement inside the while loop handles the different options.
3. The '-v' option is encountered first, so it prints "802".
4. The '-n' option is encountered next, and the argument following it is "5". The program sets **`num_set`** to 1 and converts the argument to an integer using **`atoi`**. It then prints "5".
5. The '-o' option is encountered last, and the argument following it is "4026". The program calculates the length of the argument using **`strlen`** and prints "4" since the length is 4.
6. Finally, since **`num_set`** is set to 1, the program exits with a return value of 0.

So the complete output is "80254026".

What's the flaw in this thinking process, and what will the actual output be?

Comment: The numbered steps of your analysis looks fine, but perhaps go through them again (for yourself) to explain why you think they result in the output `80254026`.

Comment: What exact bullet of yours appends `026` to the expected output?

Comment: @JohnBollinger The output is "80254" because the program prints "802" for the "-v" option, "5" for the "-n" option with the argument "5", and "4" for the "-o" option with the argument "4026". as the other commenter pointed out, maybe 026 is not a part of the output. I mean that's what I am assuming, but i'm not very confident about my answer.

Comment: @JSharma, what you just said in your comment about the expected output is different from what you say about it in the question itself.  I'm now left wondering what you are actually asking.  You seem to be confident that `80254026` is not the correct answer, and I agree.  And my previous point was that the analysis given in the question also agrees.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah, I am asking what the output would be because I am confused about the answer and think that mine is not correct. I changed my answer in the comment because of the comment @/yeputons which pointed out that 026 should not be in the output.

Comment: I have already confirmed that the numbered steps of your analysis look fine, and several others seem to agree with me.  I have also observed that they predict a different result than the question says you expected.  That's as much homework help as I'm prepared to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct Output** : `80254`

#### Explanation of Execution

The binary file is ran using : `./prog -vn 5 -o 4026`
Let's breakdown what's happening inside the while loop
The while loop parse the command line arguments given, i.e., `-vn 5 -o 4026`
It is parsed using [getopt](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getopt-function-in-c-to-parse-command-line-arguments/) which is generally used to pass flags/switches through command line arguments.
How those command line values are treated is given inside Switch case

- 'v': simply prints 802 as a string nothing more
- 'n': in the first statement it sets the value of numset to 1 to indicate that there is a value provided for the `flag -n`. Then it prints the given value in the form of an Integer [note if the value is not an Integer type it may raise an Exception]
- 'o': it calculates the length of the string provided ahead of it `4026` and stores it inside the `len` variable and then prints it. [this is the part which you got wrong]

So first -v case prints 802
Then -n case prints 5
And finally, -o prints 4 (the length of string "4026")

Another example would be
Command : `./prog -vn 100 -o abcde`
Output : 8021005